# How do I import a PDF to create a Mathematica presentation that works?

Tags: pdf-format, slideshows

I have a large PDF presentation that I would like to turn into a Mathematica notebook presentation. I know how to use PDFImport and export a Mathematica Presentation to a PDF and create a Mathematica presentation. I am wondering how to go from PDF view to Mathematica view. Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you would like to do with this? I mean this as in, when you import the PDF presentation, do you want to just show it I using Mathematica? Is there any added functionality you want to gain from importing a PDF presentation into Mathematica? From my understanding all you would get is a list of PDF slides? I don’t expect there is a way to convert said PDF slides to be interactive using the notebook interface, that would require a lot of assumptions on the part of the import parser.

Comment: I have a presentation on Java that I would like to turn into a Wolfram notebook with text. You're right about that to make it work the parser would have to make a lot of assumptions. I am curious whether there is a way to create a cell for each slide either with the image or the text. For example, if I had a 7 slide document I would have 7 cells with the text or image from each slide.

Comment: I think that would be possible, definitely, but you would likely have to train a neural network to do something like that. Detecting the text, detecting the image, separating them, etc. Certainly, there is nothing that exists, to my knowledge, that does such a thing automatically in Mathematica. It is possible to build something like that, but I do not think it currently exists.

Comment: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/12/launching-version-12-2-of-wolfram-language-mathematica-228-new-functions-and-much-more/ . The article has info on importing various items from pdfs such as plaintext, images, urls etc. The automation, however, ends there.

Comment: I think PDFs are hard to import because there is no set format unlike Word Documents where, although there may be additional data such as images, tables, charts, and diagrams embedded, the app has a built-in line-by-line structure.